# Should "I'm a noob" change our view?

Tags: discussion, new-users, etiquette

Many questions on SO nowadays are from noobs. First, should we edit out the part *"I'm a noob"* or *"I'm new to ..."* or we should leave it? And second, should we change our answer from an expert solution to an easier solution and add more details if the OP says *"I'm a noob"* in this field?

My question is different from the suggested duplicate, because the second part of my question is more important to me!

Comment: On Meta.SE: [Should we remove "I'm a newbie so please help me" lines?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97620)

Comment: @JoshCaswell , it's only one part of question

Comment: [How to flag a double question that is a duplicate of two others?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182349)

Comment: @JoshCaswell , and where is the second part?

Comment: In fact, many of the answers at the proposed duplicate address both questions that you've asked.

Comment: The only reason it might matter is that you might take more time explaining fundamental concepts you would take for granted with an experienced programmer. For example, with an experienced programmer, I'd just say "declare an array of blah blah," but with a beginner, I'd explain what that means and maybe show them how to declare such an array. The statement "I'm a noob" isn't relevant, though, it is the context of the question itself—how basic is it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tend to, as it has no bearing on the actual question being asked - it is not relevant so should be removed together with anything else that is not relevant (hi, thanks etc...).

We should be focusing on the post, not the poster.

Answer (score 6):

There shouldn't need to be an "easier solution" presented to a self proclaimed new user to a field or technology. There should only be the best practice approach as far as you are aware.

The reason why it shouldn't be different is that overall, Stack Overflow posts are not supposed to be written in a void for one user. **The posts here are supposed to generate knowledge for future visitors** and custom tailoring a response to a single user detracts from that aim.